# CSS touch like scroll using mouse

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

How can I add mouse scroll option in my angular app similar to what's present for touch screen devices in which you scroll via holding screen alongside some left or right swipe movement. How can I implement similar scroll technique using mouse so that user can click at some empty area than while holding down the click move mouse in a specific direction to scroll respectively.

Similar to what's available for trello.com:

[image]

I would prefer to implement this behavior using pure CSS as chrome's inspector tools also provides this feature while testing site's responsiveness for different screen sizes. So if its possible via CSS it would be great.

[image]

If it won't be possible via CSS then I would like to implement using JavaScript or TypeScript.

Comment: Since you haven't posted any of your code I will just link you a sample codepen: https://codepen.io/JTParrett/pen/rkofB and a js library https://github.com/asvd/dragscroll. Both with slight modifications will help you achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this library: http://hammerjs.github.io/. It covers a large range of gestures you might be interested in.